# Is there a more efficient way to convert periodicity of an intraday OHLC DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas

In Python, using the pandas library I would like to convert my minutely data into daily data.

After loading in the data (from a csv) and making a `DatetimeIndex` as the index the object `xx` looks like the following:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 540949 entries, 2007-01-02 09:46:00+08:00 to 2013-10-17 16:15:00+08:00 
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Open      540949  non-null values
High      540949  non-null values
Low       540949  non-null values
Close     540949  non-null values
Volume    540949  non-null values
dtypes: int64(5)
```

I would now like to convert this intra-day data into daily OHLC data.

My initial attempts looks like the below:

```
xx['date'] = [i.date() for i in xx.index]
xx['dailyOpen'] = xx.groupby('date').Open.transform(lambda s: s[0])
xx['dailyHigh'] = xx.groupby('date').High.transform(lambda s: s.max())
xx['dailyLow'] = xx.groupby('date').Low.transform(lambda s: s.min())
xx['dailyClose'] = xx.groupby('date').Close.transform(lambda s: s[len(s)-1])
dd  = xx.groupby('date').tail(1)[['dailyOpen','dailyHigh','dailyLow','dailyClose']]
dd.head()
```

Is there a more efficient/eloquent way of doing this?

*NOTE*

I just found this method...which is neater...but is there a way perhaps using `resample` and if using this method could I convert a minutely OHLC timeseries into a 15 minute timeseries OHLC? (N.B. there can be some missing minutes so splitting by every 15 rows wont work...)

```
def ohlcsum(df):
    df = df.sort()
    return {
       'Open': df['Open'][0],
       'High': df['High'].max(),
       'Low': df['Low'].min(),
       'Close': df['Close'][-1],
       'Volume': df['Volume'].sum()
      }

xx.groupby('date').agg(ohlcsum)
```

Also would rather than making a date column by writing something like this

```
xx['date'] = [i.date() for i in xx.index]
```

Would it be possible to use the `TimeGrouper('1D')` function to be able to group by date?

I tried using the following but for some reason it doesn't seem to work...

```
xx.groupby(TimeGrouper('1D')).agg(ohlcsum)
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

In master/0.13 (releasing very shortly), you can do this (in 0.12 this is a bit more manual to do, as you have to do it on the series individually)

```
In [7]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000,2),index=date_range('20130101 09:00:00',periods=10000,freq='1Min'),columns=['last','volume'])

In [8]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 10000 entries, 2013-01-01 09:00:00 to 2013-01-08 07:39:00
Freq: T
Data columns (total 2 columns):
last      10000  non-null values
volume    10000  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2)
In [9]: df.resample('1D',how='ohlc')
Out[9]: 
                last                                  volume                              
                open      high       low     close      open      high       low     close
2013-01-01  0.801982  3.343166 -3.203291 -0.361502  0.255356  2.723863 -3.319414  1.073376
2013-01-02  0.101687  3.378843 -3.219792 -1.121900  1.226099  4.103099 -3.463014 -0.452594
2013-01-03 -0.051806  4.290010 -4.099700 -0.637321  0.713189  3.622728 -3.236652 -0.104458
2013-01-04  0.821215  3.058024 -3.907862 -1.595449  0.836234  2.821551 -3.191774 -0.399603
2013-01-05  0.084973  3.458210 -3.191455  1.426380 -0.402435  2.777447 -2.966165  1.227398
2013-01-06 -0.669922  3.232865 -3.902237  1.846017 -0.440055  3.088109 -3.710640  3.066725
2013-01-07 -0.122727  3.300163 -3.315501  1.718163  1.085066  3.373251 -4.029679  0.187828
2013-01-08  0.311785  3.073488 -3.013702 -0.627721 -0.502258  2.795292 -2.772738 -0.654676

[8 rows x 8 columns]
```

This will work in 0.12

```
pd.concat(dict([ (k,df[k].resample('1D',how='ohlc')) for k in df.columns ]),axis=1)
```

Comment: Is the new function in 0.13 going to have sum function for volume?

Comment: no, you would have to specifically do that; easier IMHO to just ohlc on say last, them do a separate sum on volume and concat anyhow

Comment: Using the `ohlcsum` function mentioned in the question, is there a way to use `.resample('15Min',how=ohlcsum)` somehow? i.e. someting that will directly calculate the ohlcv every 15 minutes?

Comment: having looked at what is written about pandas v0.13 in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#v0-13-0-january-3-2014 it doesn't look like the ohlc functionality was adjusted...did it just not get documented, or was it not implemented?

Comment: that's the most prominent; see the full release notes: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/release.html#id3, issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2320

Comment: do i need to install v0.13 from source or would `pip install --upgrade pandas` work? also when trying `xx.groupby(TimeGrouper('1D')).agg(ohlcsum)` I was hoping it might do something similar (as mentioned in my question edits), do you have any suggestions?

Comment: if you are on linux, then install from source is best (0.13 is released by pypi not updated as of yet, binaries are on pydata.org fo rwindows).

Comment: Thanks! any thoughts on `xx.groupby(TimeGrouper('1D')).agg(ohlcsum)` at all?

Comment: that is equivalent of ``df.resample('1D',how=ohlcsum)``; you may need to futz with the return value of ohlcsum (try it as a DataFrame maybe with an index of the date, the columns as the values)

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to pandas and python but I came up with this which allows conversion to any time period

In my example, minData is minute data, stored in a flat format without any commas. My data came from quantquote.com

```
columnHeadings = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Split Factor', 'Earnings', 'Dividends']

minData = pd.read_csv(
    filename,
    header = None,
    names = columnHeadings, 
    parse_dates = [["Date", "Time"]],
    date_parser = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H%M'), 
    index_col = "Date_Time",
    sep=' ')

xx = minData.to_period(freq="min")

openCol = DataFrame(xx.Open)
openCol2 = openCol.resample("M", how = 'first')

highCol = DataFrame(xx.High)
highCol2 = highCol.resample("M", how = 'max')

lowCol = DataFrame(xx.Low)
lowCol2 = lowCol.resample("M", how = 'min')

closeCol = DataFrame(xx.Close)
closeCol2 = closeCol.resample("M", how = 'last')

volumeCol = DataFrame(xx.Volume)
volumeCol2 = volumeCol.resample("M", how = 'sum')

#splitFactorCol = DataFrame(xx.SplitFactor)
#splitFactorCol.resample("M", how = 'first')


monthlyData = DataFrame(openCol2.Open)

monthlyData["High"] = highCol2.High
monthlyData["Low"] = lowCol2.Low
monthlyData["Close"] = closeCol2.Close
monthlyData["Volume"] = volumeCol2.Volume
```

I'm sure there must be a more concise method, but this works with the data I have and it allows me to use the same code to generate 15min, 1 hour, daily, weekly and monthly. And its fast.

Any improvements/comments would be gratefully received.

Kind Regards,

-Jason