# Tried to install pandas 0.13 with canopy 1.2 and now I cant "import pandas". How should I proceed?

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I was following the discussion in this thread ([Is there a more efficient way to convert periodicity of an intraday OHLC DataFrame in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688901/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-convert-periodicity-of-an-intraday-ohlc-datafra)) where @Jeff mentions that the new version of pandas (0.13) has a feature that I'd find useful.

I tried to update to pandas 0.13. but I think I've messed up my install of pandas. I cant figure out how to put it right again.

I'm new to python so tell me if I miss out something important.

My setup is Win7 64bit

Canopy v1.2 (screenshot of my "About box" is here http://www.dowce.com/~Zqy)

I ran the pandas-0.13.0.win32-py2.7.exe installer

found on this page
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas#downloads

I think I had all of my Canopy windows closed.. But given that something went wrong, I'm not sure! certainly nothing was running in python.

The installation seemed to go fine. It found my python folder in C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User  but now whenever I try to do anything related to pandas I get an error.

Here it is on the command prompt - This is the simplest example I can think of that demonstrates the problem http://www.dowce.com/~Zqz - its the same in the canopy editor. Same error

first thing I did was reboot. Then I tried to run the pandas installer again. then I ran my canopy installer again and did a 'Repair' on that. Its still broken.

I think the next thing to do is to uninstall canopy and try to install it afresh but before I do that I thought it might be wise to ask for some help

Any ideas ?

Comment: I believe you can use the canopy package manager to upgrade/fix your pandas installation if I remember correctly.

Comment: @DavidHagan Do you know how I do this ? Is it something on the command line ? From inside the Package Manager the version will only go up to v0.12 http://www.dowce.com/~Zqg

Comment: I just checked mine and it looks like they haven't updated it yet. Maybe send them an email asking when?

Comment: Thanks, we've sent them an email.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case its useful to anyone.

So the only way I found to recover from this was to use Revo Uninstaller (http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) to unintstall the pandas 0.13 install, running an 'advanced' revo uninstall and then having the Revo uninstaller remove all of the extra files that it finds inside Enthought Canopy.

Other things I tried before coming to this conclusion: When I tried reinstalling canopy it made no difference. same with pandas 0.13. Also, uninstalling pandas made no difference (canopy should have gone back to pandas 0.12 - it didnt) uninstalling canopy and reinstalling didnt make any difference.

Strangely, Enthought Canopy didnt appear in the Revo uninstaller list. Meaning I couldnt uninstall it with revoo directly - and the standard canopy installer doesnt remove all of its own files. It doesnt really uninstall.

So that was it.. use Revo and uninstall pandas 0.13 and get the revo installer to remove all the associated files, which wipes out canopy as well.

then just reinstall Canopy and dont bother reinstalling pandas 0.13!

I have no idea why the pandas 0.13 installer broke my system like this.

My wife sent an email to Canopy to ask them to update to pandas 0.13